# How to get DriverKit System Extension log output

Tags: macos, macos-catalina, driverkit, macos-system-extension

In this part of the [2019 WWDC session demo of DriverKit System Extensions](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/702/?time=1548) you can see the driver and only the driver's log output being streamed using this command:

```
log stream --predicate 'sender = "MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver.dext"' --style syslog
```

I get no output, even when I add `--debug` and I do not know why. As far as I can tell, my extension lists the same as in `ps`. The presenter's output appears to come from `kernel.development[0]` and I have `kernel[0]`. I don't have a development kernel - is this why I see nothing?

If the above does not work, how can you conveniently monitor your extension's log output?

**UPDATE**
The predicate works with your bundle ID or `IOUserServerName` (not sure which, they're the same in [USBApp](https://github.com/knightsc/USBApp)), but only with `log show`, which reads from a file which is written occasionally, for me I think it was last updated on reboot:

```
log show --predicate 'sender == "sc.knight.MyUserUSBInterfaceDriver"'
```

But `log stream` gives me nothing, even when replacing the predicate with  `--process pid`.

Answer (score 0):

Not an optimal answer, but I use `log stream | grep "My.Bundle"`